# find() not working when string contains a letter (Works on localhost, not on server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I currently have a model `Books` which stores details including the book's `isbn`.

I use this method to search for books (actually only using their ISBN's)

```
def self.search(search)
 search_condition = "%" + search.downcase + "%"
 find(:all, :conditions => ['(isbn LIKE ? OR lower(title) LIKE ? OR lower(author) LIKE ? OR lower(edition) LIKE ? OR lower(publisher) LIKE ?) AND removed_on IS NULL', search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition])
end
```

What bothers me is that on my local machine, if I search "076374591X" I get all the books with that ISBN, but on my app on Heroku it does not return anything. I tried removing the "X" and only searching "076374591" and that works on both. It is as if the "X" in the ISBN breaks it (but only on the server).

Take note `isbn` is a `:string`.

What can possibly cause this issue, and how can I solve it?

Comment: What version of ruby are you running on Heroku and on your local machine? Also, are you running postgres locally?

Comment: @NoahClark No, running SQLite locally and Postgres on heroku. Not sure about version, Local is newest version, I guess heroku too.

Comment: have you checked that the locale is the same in both environments?

Comment: if you do `heroku version` you will get the rails version you're running. If these are the same, I'd say it could be the way postgres is running the SQL statement. Might be worth looking at `heroku logs` and pasting the SQL statement into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search by ISBN case-sensitive, but downcased search term first. So you should find "076374591x", but not "076374591X".

Try to lower isbn too:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['(lower(isbn) LIKE ? OR lower(title) ...
```

Comment: I have tested both cases. It is saved in uppercase though.

Comment: If the book stored with isbn "076374591X" (uppercase) your search will find nothing since the search term is lowercased ("076374591X" -> "076374591x", "076374591x" -> "076374591x"). You have lowercased title, author, editor, etc. but not isbn. Try to lower it too.

Comment: Oooh! Sorry, I see you were correct. I missed the search.downcase and thought that entering the string with "x" and "X" would have different effect, although they're just being downcased. Thanks!